# Get all values of a nested JSON object using any lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

Scenario: I have a variable JSON

```
var json = {
    "order": {
        "orderDetails": [{
            "a1": "b1",
            "c1": "d1",
            "e1": "f1"
        }, {
            "a1": "b2",
            "c1": "d2",
            "e1": "f2"
        }, {
            "a1": "b3",
            "c1": "d3",
            "e1": "f3"
        }],
        "orderHeader": [{
            "a2": "b1",
            "c2": "d1",
            "e2": "f1"
        }, {
            "a2": "b2",
            "c2": "d2",
            "e2": "f2"
        }]
    }
};
```

I need to get an array of all the values of `order.orderdetails.a1` like

```
['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
```

Comment: `all the vaues of order.orderdetails.a1` ... `order.orderdetails.a1` would be undefined

Comment: @jaromandaX all the values of a1 means ,the values of a1 in array orderdetails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), [lodash](https://lodash.com/) included, why not taking advantage of them instead of reinventing the wheel.

How about single-line using [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map). `_.map` also accepts strings as *iteratee* and will return the value of that key from the passed object.

```
_.map(json.order.orderDetails, 'a1')
```

```js
var json = {
    "order": {
        "orderDetails": [{
            "a1": "b1",
            "c1": "d1",
            "e1": "f1"
        }, {
            "a1": "b2",
            "c1": "d2",
            "e1": "f2"
        }, {
            "a1": "b3",
            "c1": "d3",
            "e1": "f3"
        }],
        "orderHeader": [{
            "a2": "b1",
            "c2": "d1",
            "e2": "f1"
        }, {
            "a2": "b2",
            "c2": "d2",
            "e2": "f2"
        }]
    }
};

var result = _.map(json.order.orderDetails, 'a1');

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4); // For Demo: Showing the result on the screen
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.0/lodash.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

This is similar to [`_.pluck`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/doc/README.md#_pluckcollection-path) in older versions of lodash.

```
_.pluck(json.order.orderDetails, 'a1')
```

---

The same result can be achieved in pure JavaScript using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
json.order.orderDetails.map(e => e.a1)
```

```js
var json = {
    "order": {
        "orderDetails": [{
            "a1": "b1",
            "c1": "d1",
            "e1": "f1"
        }, {
            "a1": "b2",
            "c1": "d2",
            "e1": "f2"
        }, {
            "a1": "b3",
            "c1": "d3",
            "e1": "f3"
        }],
        "orderHeader": [{
            "a2": "b1",
            "c2": "d1",
            "e2": "f1"
        }, {
            "a2": "b2",
            "c2": "d2",
            "e2": "f2"
        }]
    }
};

var result = json.order.orderDetails.map(e => e.a1);
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to do so.

```js
var json={
              "order": {
                "orderDetails": [
                  {
                    "a1": "b1",
                    "c1": "d1",
                    "e1": "f1"
                  },
                  {
                    "a1": "b2",
                    "c1": "d2",
                    "e1": "f2"
                  },
                  {
                    "a1": "b3",
                    "c1": "d3",
                    "e1": "f3"
                  }
                ],
                "orderHeader": [
                  {
                    "a2": "b1",
                    "c2": "d1",
                    "e2": "f1"
                  },
                  {
                    "a2": "b2",
                    "c2": "d2",
                    "e2": "f2"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }

var a1 = json.order.orderDetails.map(function(obj){ return obj.a1 });
console.log(a1);
```

Comment: Thank you sachin.Im new to js and didnt knew the map(). could you also help me find the value of "b1key" incase there is nested array,like
"orderDetails": [
                  {
                    "a1": ["b1key": "b1value"],
                    "c1": "d1",
                    "e1": "f1"
                  },

Comment: well there's no nested array, but nested objects.. and your welcome :)

Comment: btw value of a1 in this case is still an object, not an array. `[ { "a1": {"b1key": "b1value"}, "c1": "d1", "e1": "f1" }` and you will get it via same function with different return statement like this: `return obj.a1.b1key`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var json = {
   "order": {
     "orderDetails": [{
       "a1": "b1",
       "c1": "d1",
       "e1": "f1"
     }, {
       "a1": "b2",
       "c1": "d2",
       "e1": "f2"
     }, {
       "a1": "b3",
       "c1": "d3",
       "e1": "f3"
     }],
     "orderHeader": [{
       "a2": "b1",
       "c2": "d1",
       "e2": "f1"
     }, {
       "a2": "b2",
       "c2": "d2",
       "e2": "f2"
     }]
   }
 }

 var result = {};

// Loop over props of "order"
 for (var order in json.order){
   
   // Each prop is array. Loop over them
   json.order[order].forEach(function(item) {
     
     // Loop over each object's prop
     for (var key in item) {
       
       // Check if result has a prop with key. If not initialize it.
       if (!result[key])
         result[key] = [];

       // Push vaues to necessary array
       result[key].push(item[key]);
     }
   })
 };

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi rajesh,Thank you for the help.But im looking for a library function so that there will be less code to maintain

Comment: Thats Alright. I'll still keep my answer. You can use it as a reference. :-)